# How do I specify the order of a cumsum operation?

Tags: r

I have a dataset `counts.df` data frame that has the number of insurers in a county as well as the population of that county. I want to add a column that gives the cumulative population that lives in counties with at least as many insurers.

I can get this done by first sorting `counts.df` on `number.of.insurers` and then applying `cumsum`:

```
counts.df<-counts.df[with(counts.df,order(-number.of.insurers)),]
counts.df$cum.pop<-cumsum(counts.df$pop)
```

This code feels fragile though because the sorting step could get lost and I'm essentially mutating the dataframe and relying on it's current state for `cumsum` to work, which feels very un-R.

My question is: is there an explicit way to tell `cumsum` what order to use without sorting the data frame as a separate step?

Comment: Nope. you're going to need to sort. This is a case where the `dplyr` style chain may make things more clear: `counts.df %>% arrange(-number.of.insurers) %>% mutate(cumpop=cumsum(pop))`. You could write your own function to do the sorting and summing if you really want to. But there's nothing built in for that.

Comment: No. Just sort the data right before the cumsum.

Comment: Someone should post their comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. you're going to need to sort. This is a case where the dplyr style chain may make things more clear:

```
counts.df %>% 
  arrange(-number.of.insurers) %>% 
  mutate(cumpop=cumsum(pop))
```

You could write your own function to do the sorting and summing if you really want to. But there's nothing built in for that.

```
sortcumsum <- function(x, ordered_by=seq_along(x)) {
    idx <- order(ordered_by)
    cumsum(x[idx])[order(idx)]
}
```

and use it like

```
counts.df$cum.pop <- sortcumsum(counts.df$pop, -counts.df$number.of.insurers)
```

Comment: `sortcumsum` would return a sorted vector, right? Can we modify this so that after it generates the cumsum vector it rearranges the result to reflect the original order of `x`?